# Select2 disable/enable results in dropdown

Tags: yii

I'm working with Yii and select2. How can I initilize all the results in the dropdown disabled and enable them dynamically? Actually I did this for disable all the results:

```
$('#select2').on('open', function(e) {
    $('#select2 option').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

I checked the options in the html code an all are disabled:

```
<option value="222" disabled="disabled> first </option>
```

But I can still choose them.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for disabling dropdown

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select2").prop("disabled",true); // do it like this
});
</script>
```